# Symbolic link becomes unreadable after prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0);

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, password, symlink, core-dump

I was debugging `kcheckpass` under `Archlinux`. (Because I failed to login with `kcheckpass`)

Somehow I believe this particular problem is not within `kcheckpass`.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef HAVE_PAM
  const char    *caller = KSCREENSAVER_PAM_SERVICE;
#endif
  const char    *method = "classic";
  const char    *username = 0;
#ifdef ACCEPT_ENV
  char      *p;
#endif
  struct passwd *pw;
  int       c, nfd, lfd;
  uid_t     uid;
  time_t    nexttime;
  AuthReturn    ret;
  struct flock lk;
  char fname[64], fcont[64];

  // disable ptrace on kcheckpass
#if HAVE_PR_SET_DUMPABLE
  prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0);
```

Before the execution of the very first line: `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0);`

```
ls /proc/$(pidof kcheckpass)/exe  -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wuyihao wuyihao 0 Jan 16 16:16 /proc/31661/exe -> /cker/src/build/kcheckpass/kcheckpass
```

And after executing it:

```
ls /proc/$(pidof kcheckpass)/exe  -al
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/31661/exe': Permission denied
```

The same with `/proc/31661/root` and `/proc/31661/cwd`

I don't see any connection between `coredump` and read permission of `/proc/$PID/exe`

**UPDATE**

Minimal example reproduced this problem:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE2**
`kcheckpass` and minimal example `test` are both:

`-rwsr-xr-x  1 root    root`

Comment: BTW, I got my `kcheckpass` working, by reinstall `libpam`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the dumpable attribute, a bunch of `/proc/<pid>/` files and links becomes unreadable by other processes, even owned by the user.

[The `prctl` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) reads:

> Processes that are not dumpable can not be attached via
>   [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) PTRACE_ATTACH; see [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) for further details.
>
> If a process is not dumpable, the ownership of files in the
>   process's `/proc/[pid]` directory is affected as described in [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

And [the `proc` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) reads:

> `/proc/[pid]`
>
> Each `/proc/[pid]` subdirectory contains the pseudo-files and
>   directories described below.  These files are normally owned
>   by the effective user and effective group ID of the process.
>   However, as a security measure, the ownership is made
>   root:root if the process's "dumpable" attribute is set to a
>   value other than 1.

And finally, [the `ptrace` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) reads:

> **Ptrace access mode checking**
>
> Various parts of the kernel-user-space API (not just `ptrace()`
>   operations), require so-called "ptrace access mode" checks, whose
>   outcome determines whether an operation is permitted (or, in a few
>   cases, causes a "read" operation to return sanitized data).
>
> (...)
>
> The algorithm employed for ptrace access mode checking determines
>   whether the calling process is allowed to perform the corresponding
>   action on the target process.  (In the case of opening `/proc/[pid]`
>   files, the "calling process" is the one opening the file, and the
>   process with the corresponding PID is the "target process".)  The
>   algorithm is as follows:
>
> (...)
>
> 4. Deny access if the target process "dumpable" attribute has a
>      value other than 1 (...), and the caller does not have the
>      `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability in the user namespace of the target process.